# HTC One: DropBoxManagerService goes haywire after upgrade to KitKat 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-service, android-4.4-kitkat

I have noticed that the LOGCAT of my HTC One is getting flooded with messages from a "DropBoxManagerService" after I upgraded my device to Android KitKat 4.4.2.

I'm seeing this message repeated over and over again:

> 02-28 16:37:39.089     773-1376/? D/DropBoxManagerService﹕ Found time mapping 1393414988780 -> 1393414988780

It's outputting so fast that IntelliJ Idea's LOGCAT window is complaining: **"Too much output to process"**. It can go on for hours before it settles down, and then starts again at some (apparently) arbitrary point in time.

I have tried to reset and disable the DropBox App, but it doesn't help. I'm suspecting this "infinite loop"-like behavior to be the culprit for a heavy battery drain issue, so I'm desperately trying to find a solution for the problem.

The service name is not getting listed by task-killer Apps.

Any good ideas are happily received!

Comment: Seems to be an Android system service: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/DropBoxManager.html - however I have still no clue why it goes haywire like that.

Comment: Tried installing new software update 4.19.401.11 received on 2014-03-29. No improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried reset htc one max to factory setting. It works.

The annoyed log will disappear.

Comment: A less extreme solution would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I was told by a HTC Taiwan customer support manager that this is a bug of Google Play Service for Android 4.4.2 Kitkat, and all Android phone manufacturers like Samsung, Sony, etc. also suffers from this bug. (I wonder if it is true?) Please wait for update from Google.

I found this DropBoxManagerService message flooding bug will be triggered when there are new app updates available in Google Play Store. I can't see the update notification but my phone will become hot and battery drains fast. Reboot the phone will stop this flooding temporarily and Google Play Store will show update message immediately after reboot.

By the way, "Wipe cache partitions" does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wipe the device's cache partition. After that the issue is solved as I noticed so far. No DropBoxManagerService flooding and no battery drain.

- Hold power button and volume down key together until device powers off and you see black screen
- Release power button only while you still keep holding down volume down key
- Release volume down key when you see OS menu options
- Use volume up/down keys to scroll and highlight "recovery" and press power button to select
- When you see the icon that looks like a phone and orange "!" mark in a triangle, press power button and volume up key together once
- It will display more options
- Scroll to "wipe cache partitions" and press power button to select
- Once wiping cache partitions is completed, select reboot

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just gave it a try. Will get back in a few days when I know whether it worked for me or not.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for either. It still occurs a couple of times during a week. A device reboot seems to temporarily make it settle down. I hope the upcoming upgrade to Sence6.0 will fix it permanently.